# CSS layout problems

Tags: html, css

I am facing the problem where my page content suppose to be inside of `<div id="content">` which is the grey box, all other pages is located inside the content except this.

[image]

This is the code named `home1.php` that I have tried so far. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2vteet6/)

This is snippet code from my `index.php`

```
<div id="content">

    <?php include_once("home1.php"); ?>

</div>
```

I have suspected that code from CSS giving me this problem and can you guys give me solution to overcome this. Many thanks (Sorry for my bad English)

**UPDATE**

After add `float:none` suggested by PhillipXT , it works but the arrangement should be "pengumuman" on the left side and "2nd Content Area" on left side.
[image]

Comment: please no downvote to the answers as they gave me idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used your code because it contains broken html and elements that shouldent be inside other elements. 
But this is the basic structure of a layout you could use for "two column layout".

You float the container divs and clearfix the container. Clearfix will fix your floating problems. [Read about clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz8y6jg8/1/)

```
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="left_container">

  </div>
  <div class="right_container">

  </div>
</div>

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container {}

.left_container {
  background-color: aqua;
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
}

.right_container {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This uses the same styling to fix the problem as my answer, but it's a little neater since you don't need the extra empty div tag.  I'll have to remember that...

Comment: It's a bit different, but check the clearfix link and read about it ;) @PhillipXT

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use too many floats.
You may consider using inline-block or

flexbox (if you dont' care about IE9)

Comment: Is it means that IE9 will not support?

Comment: inline-block will work everywhere
flexbox in modern browsers only

two column layout with clearfix will work almost everywhere.